# InApp purchase model issue if the user installs again the application

Tags: ios, in-app

I developed a mobile application  for testing the relative compressions of both petrol and diesel engines and hence their mechanical condition.
To make the application more attractive, I would like  to implement an In-App purchase business model based on :

- the five first compression tests for free
- and then buy 5 compressions for 5$ for example

But what happens if the user installs the application, makes 5 tests for free, removes the application and installs it a second time?
In my opinion, the user "wins" 5 more test for free.
What could be the process to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot for your support.
Best regards.

Jean-Francois

Comment: The quick and easy way is to store a value in KeyChain. This will remain across app reinstalls, but not across device resets. You can also use [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck). This works across device resets.

Comment: Dear Paul, Thanks a lot for your reply, I will take a closer look at your link.